# Set client Quotas on a windows server

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, file-sharing, user-management, quota

I'm using winserver 2012 to Share files over a network of about 100 users. Currently anyone connected to the network has full access to the shared folders. I would like to limit each client to a certain amount of MB, but cannot find a way to do it. What would be the best way to manage client space quotas on winserver? are there better options on a linux server?

I do not need to limit users access to the shared folders, the shared files can be accessed by all users. I only need to limit each clients memory usage.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831701(v=ws.11).aspx